# Git push error RPC failed curl 52 GnuTLS recv error (-110)

Tags: git, github, git-push

I used the command `git add .` to add all files on the repository but later realized that I need to push just one file and so I cancelled this command midway using `Ctrl+C`, but now when I try to push the intended file using `git push origin master`, I get the following ouput:

```
Delta compression using up to 24 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 1.08 KiB | 1.08 MiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 52 GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

When I check my repository on github, I see that my file is not pushed.
I am able to push from a different machine but there seems to be a problem with the current machine that I don't understand.

Comment: What operating system and version of Git are you using?  Are you using a proxy or TLS middlebox on your network, or, if under WSL, a non-default antivirus or firewall on your machine?

Comment: Note: Git doesn't push *files*, it pushes *commits*. One Git sends whole commits to another Git. Either the other Git has the commit (in which case, it doesn't need to be sent again), or it doesn't (in which case the whole commit will be sent again). This isn't too important with respect to the error message you're seeing, but it's worth remembering when it comes to using Git later, once you get past this problem. (bk2204's questions are probably the key to solving this problem.)

Comment: @bk2204 I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and a git version 2.17.1. As for your other questions, I am sorry but I don't understand these terms

Comment: @bk2204 and I'm neither using proxy nor WSL.